# Saving Dictionary contents to file

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to do something pretty specific with lists and counting unique instances, then saving that on a new line in a file.

Essentially, I have a listview with a set of columns, I want to loop through the whole list, and save a count of each unique item.

Example, a list like so;

```
111
222
111
333
333
333
```

would end up being written to file as:

```
111:2
222:1
333:3
```

I dont need it to be in any particular order, just so long as I have those values.

So far I have this;

```
string fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\txn_" + 
    TerminalConfig.CreateSafSig() + ".saf";

Dictionary<string, int> products = new Dictionary<string, int>();
List<string> codes = new List<string>();

foreach (ListViewItem item in BasketList.Items)
{ 
    codes.Add(item.SubItems[3].Text); 
}

String[] items = codes.ToArray();
foreach (String code in items)
{
    if (products.ContainsKey(code) != true)
    { 
        products.Add(code, 1); 
    }
    else 
    { 
        products[code] += 1; 
    }
}

foreach (var entry in products)
{ 
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, string.Format("{0}:{1}",entry.Key,entry.Value)); 
}
```

But the file it saves is only giving me what would be the last line.
in the example above, it would only show `333:3`

I was pretty sure I wrote it correctly, and I'm struggling to find where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you overwrite the file with every iteration of the loop.

Code fix:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();


foreach (var entry in products)
{
   str.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", entry.Key, entry.Value));
}
File.WriteAllText(fileName, str.ToString()); }
```

To jump on the linq bandwagon here is the code to make a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> products = 
    BasketList.Items.GroupBy(element => element.SubItems[3].Text)
                    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, c => c.Count())
```

Yes in linq that replaces all those lines in one.

Comment: My appologies, that was a schoolboy error, I should have seen that a mile off! Thank you for the astonishingly quick response :) Marking resolved as that's done the job wonderfully!

Answer (score 4):

`File.WriteAllText` writes a new file. You are overwriting the file each time you iterate through your for loop giving you only the last line.

The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) page shows

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes
>   the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

You could replace the `File.WriteAllText` with [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) which:

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a
>   file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

If you want to write the file all at once, you could use [`File.WriteAllLines(string path,IEnumerable<string> contents)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx); which

> Creates a new file, writes a collection of strings to the file, and
>   then closes the file.

In your case replace :

```
foreach (var entry in products)
{ 
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, string.Format("{0}:{1}",entry.Key,entry.Value)); 
}
```

with

```
var entries = from entry in products select string.Format("{0}:{1}",entry.Key,entry.Value);
File.WriteAllLines(fileName,entries);
```

Comment: [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) also overwrites a file. The only difference between the two methods is one takes an array.

Answer (score 2):

Harrison answered why your code is not working... now let me show you why Jonesy (rudely) suggested you use GroupBy...

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName,
               from item in BasketList.Items
               group item by item.SubItems[3].Text into grp
               select string.Format("{0}:{1}", grp.Key, grp.Count()));
```

This effectively replaces all of your code. It *is* less efficient -- `GroupBy` creates groups of the items when really you only need a count, so it is a bit heavyweight on memory usage -- but that isn't often a hugely important factor. There is something to be said about being succinct.

Comment: My experience with C# is entirely self-taught and there are a few things I've never even seen before. By the looks of it, your code sample has just done what my mess above was meant to, in four lines?

Comment: @FrankishEQG - Yes this uses linq, which is quite fun when you get used to it.

Comment: @CoryNelson - I think the linq solution would be clearer with a ToDictionary(). Then it could be a drop in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The WriteAllText function will overwrite the file contents with the string you supply.  You should use the AppendAllText function instead